# Meaning of 'could have done something'?

Tags: modal-verbs, perfect-aspect, can-could

In the following sentence,

> If you had tried harder you could have succeeded.

does **could have succeeded** mean **would have been able to succeed**, or **might have been able to succed**, or is it ambiguous if no further context is provided?

Comment: I take it the distinction you're thinking of is (1) *really **would** succeed*, as opposed to (2) *would have had the theoretical **capability of succeeding** (but perhaps failing to be successful anyway)*. In theory it seems possible that second sense *could* be conveyed by your cited text, but in practice no-one would understand it that way.

Comment: ...in short, for all practical purposes, *If you had tried harder you could have succeeded* is semantically identical to *If you had tried harder you **would** have succeeded* (which isn't necessarily the same thing as *...would have **been able to** succeed*).

Comment: It's down to interpretation and probably personal viewpoint (glass half full/half empty), but I think "If you tried harder you could have succeeded" means you would have had a chance if you tried harder, but with your current/past level of effort you have no chance. Certainly, it's not terribly clear. In contrast, "If you tried harder you would have succeeded" means success would be certain with more effort (although as a piece of parental wisdom, that is normally said in situations where it means "you would probably have succeeded").

Answer (score 1):

**I-** **could have succeeded**
You use this form when the **usual conditions for succeeding appeared to be met** and either when the action 1/ failed (or state failed to be realized) or 2/ was being considered before it could occur.
(*material possibility (ability) in the past*)

- The attack on the fortress **could have succeeded** as the cannons could open a breach in the wall but inside  there were as many soldiers as in three garrisons, and it failed.
- From all the information that we had gathered, this plan **could have succeeded**, and therefore we chose to implement it.

**II-** **would have been able to succeed**
You use this form when there was evidence that the **conditions for succeeding would be  met**, and either  when the action 1/ failed (or state failed to be realized) or 2/ was being considered before it could occur.
(*assumption in the past*)

- He **would have been able to succeed** since until then his grades on all subjects were excellent; there was no reason he wouldn't have had grades as good in the last year, but in that last year he had been disabled by a grievous illness and he could hardly do any studying, and so, he failed.
- He **would have been able to succeed** in those days as he had more means, but nowadays it is that very scantiness of his finances that keeps him from trying.

**III-** **might/could  have been able to succeed**
You use this form when there was a possibility for the **conditions for succeeding to be  met**,  and either  when the action 1/ failed (or state failed to be realized) or 2/ was being considered before it could occur.
(*possibility in the past   subject to no condition*)

- This team **might/could have been able to succeed** since they had  managed several times before to achieve such a task successively, but they came too late.
- Where all had failed the boy  **might/could** still **have  been able to succeed**, and so he was called to captain's tent, who briefed him for his mission.

**IV-** It follows that "**could have succeeded**" means neither "**would have been able to succeed**"  nor "**might have been able to succeed**".

Comment: basically, what I meant was that 'could have done' can be either ability in the past or possibility in the past, which makes it ambiguous... , which surprises me since ambiguity seems to be the one thing that the English language consistently tries to avoid.

Comment: @user58319 It seems to me that this  ambiguity is of recent origin and that in a not so distant past "can" was limited to the domain of the physically or conceptually possible but I can't assert that; nevertheless, I can see no necessity for adhering to this ambiguous usage.